# Strange SHA256 Behavior

Tags: java, sha256

As can be seen from the screenshot(https://jwt.io/) which is the expected signature, I am getting wrong java code. I am missing something very obvious wrong with code?

[image]

```
    package com.company;
    
    import javax.crypto.Mac;
    import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
    import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
    import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
    import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
    import java.util.Base64;
    
    public class Main {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
            final Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
            mac.init(new SecretKeySpec("qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm123456".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), "HmacSHA256"));
            String sourcString = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJPbmxpbmUgSldUIEJ1aWxkZXIiLCJpYXQiOjE2MjM5NTk5NDEsImV4cCI6MTY1NTQ5NTk0MSwiYXVkIjoid3d3LmV4YW1wbGUuY29tIiwic3ViIjoianJvY2tldEBleGFtcGxlLmNvbSIsIkdpdmVuTmFtZSI6IkpvaG5ueSIsIlN1cm5hbWUiOiJSb2NrZXQiLCJFbWFpbCI6Impyb2NrZXRAZXhhbXBsZS5jb20ifQ";
            byte[] signatureBytes = mac.doFinal(sourcString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            System.out.println("Signatured=" + Base64.getEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(signatureBytes));
        }
    }
```

**OUTPUT : Signatured=ZFrcK6AZzYCTs0ugepzcSFMxxuY5Fs0PtMXGDZtT3sA**
http://tpcg.io/P0MtSDC3

Comment: What about using base64 instead of getBytes()?

Comment: @dan1st two items joined by a dot are both already base64 encoded.

Comment: `sourcString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` is UTF-8. I meant using Base64 instead of UTF-8, here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you almost got it, since you provide the SecretKeySpec in clear text you don't have to check this check box ... or provide a clear text SecretKey that actually encodes to "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm123456".

[image: uncheck this]

Comment: If you look at code the secret key is already plain text.  mac.init(new SecretKeySpec("qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm123456".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), "HmacSHA256"));